# Nuxt 3 createError redirects to error page from a plugin or a ts file

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

currently, I'm building a Nux 3 app using Axios to handle my APIs.

I'm trying to redirect to the error page each time an Axios response is 404 globally.

this is my Axios plugin file:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const defaultUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ?
    "https://api.xxxxx.com/api/" : "http://localhost:5000/api";

  let api = axios.create({
    baseURL: defaultUrl,
    headers: {
      common: {
      }
    },
  })

  api.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
  }, (error) => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
      const user = useUser()
      console.log("token expires")
      user.isLoggedIn = false
      user.token = ""
      user.user = {}
      localStorage.removeItem("almowaraqi-admin")
      useRouter().push("/login")
    }
    if(error.response.status === 404) {
      console.log("nooot fouuund")
      console.log(error.response.data.msg);
      throw createError({
        statusCode: 404,
        message: error.response.data.msg,
      })
    }
  })
return {
    provide: {
      axios: api,
    },
  };
});
```

when I open a page/_id that is not found. I can see in my console those dummy messages
[image]

but the `throw createError()` is not working.

this is my ~/error.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
.error-page.w-full.h-screen
    .error-page-container.flex.justify-center.items-center.h-full.flex-col
        h1.text-7xl.font-bold {{ error.statusCode }}
        span.text-xl.font-medium {{ error.message }}
        p.text-base we are sorry, but the page you requested was not found
        button(@click="handleError").btn.rounded-xl.btn-primary.my-5 Go to home
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps(['error'])

const handleError = () => clearError({ redirect: '/' });
</script>
```

how can I apply the `throw createError()` in my plugin or in my .ts files.
and Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to Nuxt 3 documentation [nuxt 3 documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#showerror)

I used the `showError()` function instead of `createError()`

```
throw showError({
   statusCode: 404,
   fatal: true,
   message: error.response.data.msg
})
```